# Magento 2 : Minicart not Updating

Tags: magento2, addtocart, mini-cart

I installed Magento 2.0.12 with sample data. I press add to cart button but minicart is not working (keeps updating but nothing happens ie stuck). See below.

I have full page caching enabled from backend and php 7 + apache 2.4.

[image]

Comment: Have you check concol when try to add to cart?

Comment: ok, it reports following: [access_compat:error] ......... AH01797: client denied by server configuration: .......config.php

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, but changing permissions on that file (config.php) doesnt help.

Comment: 2.0.12 is too old now, please use Magento 2.1.4 with sample data.